# How can I handle _popen() errors in C?

Tags: c, windows, pipe, popen

Good morning;
Right now, I'm writing a program which makes a Montecarlo simulation of a physical process and then pipes the data generated to gnuplot to plot a graphical representation. The simulation and plotting work just fine; but I'm interested in printing an error message which informs the user that gnuplot is not installed. In order to manage this, I've tried the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
FILE *pipe_gnuplot;
int main() 
{
    pipe_gnuplot = _popen("gnuplot -persist", "w");
    if (pipe_gnuplot==NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR. INSTALL gnuplot FIRST!\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But, instead of printing my error message, "gnuplot is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" appears (the program runs on Windows). I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. According to _popen documentation, NULL should be returned if the pipe opening fails. Can you help me managing this issue? Thanks in advance and sorry if the question is very basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error handling of `popen` (or `_popen`) is difficult.

`popen` creates a pipe and a process. If this fails, you will get a `NULL` result, but this occurs only in rare cases. (no more system resources to create a pipe or process or wrong second argument)

`popen` passes your command line to a shell (UNIX) or to the command processor (Windows). I'm not sure if you would get a `NULL` result if the system cannot execute the shell or command processor respectively.

The command line will be parsed by the shell or command processor and errors are handled as if you entered the command manually, e.g. resulting in an error message and/or a non-zero exit code.

A successful `popen` means nothing more than that the system could successfully start the shell or command processor. There is no direct way to check for errors executing the command or to get the exit code of the command.

Generally I would avoid using `popen` if possible.

If you want to program specifically for Windows, check if you can get better error handling from Windows API functions like `CreateProcess`.

Otherwise you could wrap your command in a script that checks the result and prints specific messages you can read and parse to distinguish between success and error. (I don't recommend this approach.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!. I'm going to try using `CreateProcess()`

Answer (score 1):

Just to piggy-back on @Bodo's answer, on a POSIX-compatible system you can use [`wait()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html) to wait for a single child process to return, and obtain its exit status (which would typically be 127 if the command was not found).

Since you are on Windows you have [`_cwait()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=vs-2019), but this does not appear to be compatible with how `_popen` is implemented, as it requires a handle to the child process, which `_popen` does not return or give any obvious access to.

Therefore, it seems the best thing to do is to essentially manually re-implemented `popen()` by creating a pipe manually and spawning the process with one of the `spawn[lv][p][e]` functions.  In fact the docs for [`_pipe()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/pipe?view=vs-2019#example-2) give an example of how one might do this (although in your case you want to redirect the child process's `stdin` to the write end of your pipe).

I have not tried writing an example though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In the end, I have used `CreateProcess()` and distributed my program with a copy of gnuplot in the same folder. I know that is not the ideal approach, but is an easy way of assuring that my program can launch gnuplot.